# Java - Deleting word in trie (pseudo code)

Tags: java, trie

I've been working on trying to plan out how to delete words from a trie. I have an implementation that uses a one-dimensional array on the node which holds the next characters for a word. I understand how I can get rid of a whole word but not account for larger words that contain the smaller word to be removed so trying to delete "bat", "battle", "as" and "any" from the trie below  (* indicates end of word) and leaving "battery", "battlefield", "ask" and "anywho":

```
    root 
    / \
   a   b-a-t*-t-e-r-y*
  / \         |
 n   s*-k*    l-e*-f-i-e-l-d*
 |
 y*-w-h-o*
```

Below is the trie I have implemented thus far:

```
public class TrieNode {

    protected char letter = ' ';
    protected TrieNode parentNode = null;
    protected boolean fullWord = false;
    protected TrieNode[] children = new TrieNode[26];

    public TrieNode(char letter, TrieNode parentNode){
        this.letter = letter;
        this.parentNode = parentNode;
    }

    public boolean hasChildren(){
        int index = 0;

        while(index < children.length){
            if(children[index] != null) {
                return true;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public TrieNode nodeForLetter(char ch) {
        return children[ch - 97];
    }

    public boolean isEndOfWord() {
        return fullWord;
    }
}

public class Trie implements Iterable<String> {

    private int numOfNodes;
    private int numOfWords;
    private TrieNode root = new TrieNode(' ', null);

    public Trie() {
    }

    public void addWord(String s) {
        if (hasWord(s)) return;

        int index = 0;
        TrieNode iterator = root;

        while(index < s.length()){
            if(iterator.children[s.charAt(index) - 97] == null){
                iterator.children[s.charAt(index) - 97] = new TrieNode(s.charAt(index), iterator);
                numOfNodes++;
            }

            iterator = iterator.children[s.charAt(index) - 97];

            index++;

            if(index == s.length()){
                iterator.fullWord = true;
                numOfWords++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Issues on this one 
    public void deleteWord(String s) {
        if(s.length() == 0) return; 
        // make method to check for empty trie
        else if(!(hasWord(s))) return;
        else {
            TrieNode iterator = root;
            int index = 0;

            while(index < s.length()){
                if(iterator.children[index] != null){
                    /* What would (in pseudo code) need to be put here to account for this */
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean hasWord(String s) {
        TrieNode current = root;

        while(current != null){
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                if(current.letter == ' ') return false; // error here probably
                else current = current.children[i];
            }
            if (current.fullWord == true) return true;
            else return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return new TrieIterator();  // has basic iterator functions
    }

}
```

Can anyone suggest some pseudo-code to help me figure this out

Answer (score 0):

char = current position in the trie

char-1 = previous position in the trie

1. Find the word you want to delete in the trie. It will be indicated by fullWord. Change the state of fullWord.
2. Does it contain any more chars after the word? Exit.
3. Does it contain any children at the last letter? Exit.

-- removing chars from the trie
-- at this point the only option is if the word doesn't have words after it or any children, so delete
-- all chars until we find a word or any children, which indicates a new word

' 4. while the current char is not a word full and doesn't have a child: pointer=char-1; delete char; char=pointer.

' 5. Exit